# Constant version already defined in web.php

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

When running multiple tests in Laravel Dusk i get the error `Constant version already defined in web.php`, because web.php is run before each test.
How to prevent that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add

```
    protected $preserveGlobalState = FALSE;
    protected $runTestInSeparateProcess = TRUE;
```

to DuskTestClass

Source [constant already defined article](https://queirozf.com/entries/error-message-constant-already-defined-when-using-phpunit)